# facebook connect post-login url extra values

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I'm using facebook connect on my site and it works fine except for one small (but annoying) detail. Whenever a user logs in, they return to the original url they were at before except there is an extra piece added to the end of the url. For example, if the page was at www.domain.com, after logging in through facebook, the new url would be something like this:

```
www.domain.com/?state=407abe669787e4a97dc80c93d7ba5eae&code=AQDu0Vjf1hvo7N-TPmdsBygQCIxs7LfEfNMlf1aKNiyOeuAtDbIo-zTzWqWF7yv_Jsp4YOfkjQHqx17zsiCPYKxLyeL3BMdNr0HFnEu7Q50Hc2Ca92VfiDl9VWQJUDRYwjPDkpyZPJHOIkInaRA9xTivtuUtb5VCUGNvHSU7hRgb3muK-EKJ1p5iEnRjN1y7_Y8#_=_
```

I'm using the newest facebook PHP SDK (version 3.1.1 as of now) and I'm getting the login url just like in the example shown here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/ by calling

```
$facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'email', 'display' => 'touch'));
```

The url that it creates looks correct, something like this:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=124847107591285&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdomain.com&state=407abe669787e4a97dc80c93d7ba5eae&scope=email&display=touch
```

I would like it so that the url the user returns to post-login is exactly as it was, without the extra state and code values. I haven't seen anything about this mentioned in the docs and this is really bugging me.

I'm wondering if anyone else has come across this, and if so, if there is a solution for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you didn't look at the right docs page, but it says very clearly at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ what is the purpose of those two parameters:

> If the user presses **Allow**, your app is authorized. The OAuth Dialog
>   will redirect (via HTTP 302) the user's browser to the URL you passed
>   in the redirect_uri parameter with an authorization code:
>
> http://YOUR_URL?code=A_CODE_GENERATED_BY_SERVER
>
> With this **code** in hand, you can proceed to the next step, app
>   authentication, to gain the access token you need to make API calls.

As for the **state** parameter, this one is very important in preventing CSRF attacks.

> Cross site request forgery is an attack in which a trusted
>   (authenticated and authorized) user unknowingly performs an action on
>   website. To prevent this attack, you should pass an identifier in the
>   state parameter, and then validate the **state** parameter matches on the
>   response. We strongly recommend that any app implementing Facebook
>   user login implement CSRF protection using this mechanism.

To summarize, those parameters are important and are there for you to use it if you want to (and you should).

If for any reason you don't want your users to see that url you can do a check if they are set in your GET superglobal and if they are, redirect the user at the page you want, without those params beeing present.

Comment: hmm ok I don't know how I missed that. I was assuming since the PHP SDK page says "By removing the need to manage access tokens manually, the PHP SDK greatly simplifies the process of authentication and authorizing users for your app" (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/) I didn't think I had to deal with auth tokens so I wasn't sure why it was giving it to me in the url when the object in the SDK already had access to it.

In the example included in the SDK it also returns with the state and code in the URL after login. I guess I'll just do a redirect and clear out the $_GET.